# Is there a way to use the drawWindow() method on a live website?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I don't think the drawWindow() method works on a live website. Is there a way round it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's currently a Mozilla-exclusive feature, and it only works for XUL apps and Mozilla extensions.

I think you can draw windows with same domains, by the same origin policy.